# Displaying a warning instead of an error via ajax/client side checking

Tags: php, yii

When using ajax/client side checks I am able to warn a user before submission of errors they may have made in the form. Is there a possibility to instead have a warning so a user visible will see that there may be a problem with an input, just as if it was an error, but submission  will not give the user an error?

Currently I am using:

```
$this->addError($attribute, 'Duplicate mac address detected! There is '.count($results). ' other records with this address.');
```

This works for the validation before the submission, though on submit the user should not be prevented from submitting. Therefore is it possible to warn instead?

Comment: Have you tried anything to do this? You will need to use Javascript.

Comment: @jakenoble I have a field that is Regex checked via jquery and if the string is formatted incorrectly a warning is displayed, but in this case I can't do it that way as I need to perform a database query.

Comment: Why not AJAX to do the database check via javascript. Keep the server side validation though as this should always be called, do not rely on the javascript validation.

Comment: @jakenoble The built in addError is almost exactly what I want except I just want it to be a warning.

Answer (score 0):

if your intent is just showing warn message on UI then you could do this:
Instead of using `addError()`, use this `Yii::app()->user->setFlash('notice', "I am warning you");`

So in your view page:
`Yii::app()->user->getFlash('notice');`

Read from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/)

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the issue I have added a check to see if the request is an Ajax based request.

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
  //Ajax only request check here
}
```

This has solved my issue.